# The css style cannot work properly in HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: There are excess white spaces on the right of background image]

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% load static %} 

{% block content %} 
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin:0;margin-left: -15px;margin-right: -20px;padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;">
    <img src="{% static 'bg_delivery.png' %}" style="width:100%;">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

For the part of `container-fluid`, I had added styles like `margin-left: -15px;margin-right:-15px;` but there are still excess white spaces on the right of the background picture so anything is missing in the styles in order to eliminate all excess white spaces?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `margin: 0` for `body` to reset the default margin, you can erase all your style attributes from the parent div:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```